# Excel sheet joining without overwriting column

Tags: excel, join, merge

I have two excel sheets. One looks like this:

[image: Table1]

Another one like this:

[image]

And I want to merge them like this:

[image]

Sadly I have not two, but about 150 sheets which need merging. Column 2 is the same in every one of them and it has identical values. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: To answer the only question that you have posed: I'd use VBA to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work.  you will need to adjust the copy range to cater to your spreadsheets

```
Sub Merge()

Dim i As Integer

i = 1

While i <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

Sheets(i).Select

Range("B3:C6").Copy

Sheets(1).Select

Range("B3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        True, Transpose:=False

i = i + 1

Wend

Sheets(1).Select

End Sub
```